# Change SQL Query: Based on ID, Return a string - Is this possible to do without changing the table and storing the string there?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL Query in ASP:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<RequestOverview>> getRequestOverview (RequestOverview model)
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@ClaimID", model.ClaimID); 
        var getOverview = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<RequestOverview>($@"SELECT 
        TOP 1 Vehicle.ID as claimID, 
        Retailer.Name as dealerName, Retailer.Address as dealerAddress, 
        Retailer.PostAddress as dealerCity,
        Customer.Name as ownerName, Customer.StreetAddress as ownerAdress, 
        Customer.Postnumber as ownerZipCode, 
        Customer.PostAddress as ownerCity, 
        Customer.CellphoneNumber as ownerMobile, 
        Customer.Email as ownerEmail,
        Invoice.ID as warrantyInvoiceNr, 
        Invoice.PaidDate as warrantyPaymentDate, 
        Invoice.DueDate as warrantyDueDate, 
        Invoice.PaidDate as warrantyInvoiceDate, 
        InvoiceStatus.Name as InvoiceStatusID,
        Vehicle.RegNumber as vehicleRegNr, Vehicle.Brand as vehicleBrand, 
        Vehicle.Model as vehicleModel, Vehicle.YearModel 
        as vehicleYearModel, Vehicle.FirstDayInTraffic as vehicleRegDate, 
        Vehicle.MeterReading as vehicleMilage, Vehicle.Vinnumber as vehicleVinNr,
        Product.Name as warrantyProduct, Premie.Price as warrantyPrice, 
        Premie.Months as warrantyDuration, 
        Premie.Maxkilometer as warrantyDistance, 
        ProductVarySetup.MaxDistance as warrantyMaxKm, 
        Contract.ValidFrom as warrantyStartDate, 
        Contract.ValidTo as warrantyValidTo, 
        Contract.ContractNumber as warrantyContactNr, 
        ContractStatus.Name as ContractStatusID
        FROM ((Retailer
        INNER JOIN Customer ON Retailer.ID = Customer.ID
        INNER JOIN Vehicle ON Retailer.ID = Vehicle.ID
        INNER JOIN Product ON Retailer.ID = Product.ID
        INNER JOIN Premie ON Retailer.ID = Premie.ID
        INNER JOIN Contract ON Retailer.ID = Contract.ID
        INNER JOIN ProductVarySetup ON Retailer.ID = ProductVarySetup.ID
        INNER JOIN ContractStatus ON Contract.ContractStatusID = ContractStatus.ID
        INNER JOIN Invoice ON Retailer.ID = Invoice.ID
        INNER JOIN InvoiceStatus ON Invoice.InvoiceStatusID = InvoiceStatus.ID))
        WHERE (Vehicle.ID = @ClaimID); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();", parameters);
        return getOverview;
    }
```

Everything works. But as you can see I have `InvoiceStatus.Name as InvoiceStatusID` and `INNER JOIN InvoiceStatus ON Invoice.InvoiceStatusID = InvoiceStatus.ID` to get the name instead of the `ID` of the `InvoiceStatus`. However, I would like to change so that if the `ID` is 1 I would like to return the word 'Paid' and if the `ID` is anything other than 1 I would like to return 'Not Paid'. Is this possible to do without adding a new column to the `InvoiceStatus` table and storing 'paid'/'not paid' there?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
INNER JOIN InvoiceStatus ON Invoice.InvoiceStatusID = InvoiceStatus.ID
```

and replace  " InvoiceStatus.Name as InvoiceStatusID," with this

```
CASE
    WHEN Invoice.InvoiceStatusID = 1 THEN 'Paid'
    ELSE 'NotPaid'
END AS InvoiceStatusID,
```

IIF is only working at MS SQL Server 2012+. CASE is working at any server.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do an [immediate if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in your `select` statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1
       Vehicle.ID as claimID,
       ...
       IIF (Invoice.InvoiceStatusID = 1, 'Paid', 'Not Paid') AS '<AliasName>'
       ...
```

The three dots are the rest of the code.